# get auto increment id before save MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I have an application where users have to save informations to DataBase and images to file System directory and save the path of images in Database. My question is how to get the ID (auto increment) from the Database Table to make a path in the database. Exemple: car1200.jpeg (car: image name , 1200: Id of the user).
here my code :
Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add ( @RequestParam("prix") Long prix, 
            RequestParam("adresse") String ville,
            @RequestParam("categorie") String categorie,
            @RequestParam("photos") MultipartFile file,
            ) throws FileNotFoundException


 {

   String chemin=null;
   if (!file.isEmpty())
     {
      try {
       String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
       // this line to retreive just file name 
       String 
       name=orgName.substring(orgName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,orgName.length());
       chemin="e:\\images\\"+name;// here I want to add ID of the user ,I 
       //don t know how to get since it is auto increment 
       File file1=new File(chemin);
       file.transferTo(file1);
         } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }

    }
    annonce.setImage(chemin);
    annonce.setTitre(prix);
    annonce.setCorps(ville);
    annonce.setPrix(cetegorie)
    annoncedao.save(annonce);
    return "SuccessAddAnnonce";
}
```

Annonce class:

```
package com.eBenamar.Entities;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

/**
 * @author user
 *
 */
@Entity
public class Annonce implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;
    @NotEmpty
    String titre;
    Long prix;
    @Column(length=10000000)
    byte [] photos;
    public byte[] getPhotos() {
        return photos;
       }
    String ville;
    String categorie;
    @Lob
    @Column(length=10000000)
    byte []   photos;

    public Annonce() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Annonce( String ville, Long prix, String categorie,
            byte[] photos) {
        super();
        this.ville= ville;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.categorie = categorie;
        this.photos = photos;

    }



    public Annonce( String categorie, Long prix, String ville, byte[] photos) {
        super();
        this.ville= ville;
        this.categorie = categorie;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getVille() {
        return ville;
    }
    public void setTVille(String ville) {
        this.ville = ville;
    }
    public String getCategorie() {
        return categorie;
    }
    public void setCategorie(String categorie) {
        this.categorie= categorie;
    }
    public Long getPrix() {
        return prix;
    }
    public void setPrix(Long prix) {
        this.prix = prix;
    }
    public byte[] getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }
    public void setPhotos(byte[] photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }

}
```

I want to get the last ID (auto increment) saved in the database .

Comment: Why do you want to use the auto increment as part of the path?  I think it would be non trivial to do what you want here, because the auto increment value generally isn't available until after the insert has completed.

Comment: Assuming the ID you want to get is in fact the ID of the annonce, and not the ID of the user, and assuming annonce indeed has an `image` property, you'll need to save the annonce without image, flush() to make sure JPA insertes the entity and thus generates the ID, then compute the chemin and store it in the image. But since you store the image path in the entity anyway, you don't need to have the ID of the entity in the path. You could just use a sequence, or a uuid, for the image path.

Comment: Did you set auto increment column checked in your MYSQL for the column id?

Comment: JB : the problem is that I save images in the file system and I don t want to have two images with the same name so I want to add Annonce ID  to the image name in the path in the annonce table.True I can not get the ID before save but I can get the last one because it is auto increment so I will just id++

Comment: Tanmay : yes I did for MySQL auto increment.